Can householders get divine visions and spiritual powers?
Can a householder if he practices sincerely for a singnificant hours in a day , get spiritual powers and moksha, or any expertise in any of the tantra sadhana? Or does he have to move out to other places to get some powers? Also can one become as realised as the great paramahamsas being a householder or he has to renounce everything in this world?
